# Can't login to SharePoint using WebServices

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to access the files on a SharePoint-server(WOSS, 12.0.0.6421) through the WebServices but I can't sign in.

ListsService.Lists lists = new Lists();
lists.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword", "mydomain");
lists.Url = "http://sharepointhost/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
XmlNode node = lists.GetListCollection();
return node.OuterXml;

But i get 401: unauthorized on GetListCollection, but the same username and password works perfectly when i access the sharepoint through a browser.

I checked the FAQ and found this: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/896861. But I'm not developing on the servering, I'm developing on another computer.

I found another thread which showed(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/e115f790-fe8a-45e9-982b-21833ea01c7f) but when i use that solution I get "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'." which to me just seems even more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try follwoing the steps mentioned in the link and this should solve your problem.

http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-reminder/manual.aspx?Page=reminderservice%2fwssv3.htm

**Tried and Tested - It worked for me.**

HTH